# Visualizing distribution of sample proportions that takes into account of the sample proportion uncertainties

Tags: data-visualization, proportion, beta-distribution

I have calculated several sample proportions in my dataset that stem from an unknown population distribution - likely a beta mixture. I would like to perform some exploratory analysis to visualize the density of proportions in my dataset.

As a first pass, I simply visualized a histogram of the sample proportions calculated:

[image]

As you can see, majority of the sample proportions are at 0 and 1. Therefore, I wanted to see if this pattern was an artifact of the number of "trials" (success + failures that was used to calculate each sample proportion). Specifically if the peak at 0 and 1 were from events with low number of trials.

[image]

Based on the plot above, there are clusters at 0 and 1 with very low trial count, likely since sampling a low trial count has a higher chance of the sample proportion becoming 0 or 1.

I am curious to see if there is some way to plot the distribution of all sample proportions that somehow also takes into account of the sample proportion uncertainties (in a way that weights sample proportions with lower uncertainty more than sample proportions with higher uncertainty).

Perhaps potentially a solution that models each sample proportion as a beta RV? i.e. Beta(10,5) and Beta(100,50) have the same expected value proportion, yet has different variances:

[image]

Data used: https://gist.github.com/CodingBash/6eedd305ff899f2f468db21b4608c053

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset for people to work with?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Sure, here is the gist https://gist.github.com/CodingBash/6eedd305ff899f2f468db21b4608c053